# Return value from jar file created from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jar, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have got a Matlab code which at last calculates a vector of indexes. I used library compiler in order to compile matlab code to a java package .jar file.  I exported the jar file in order to run it for my main Java project. The name of the package class is Epidemic.  I imported the jar file (add it as an external jar). In main code I tried to create an object of my class (in jar file). I have already defined the name of the class as Epidemic. Thus, my code:

```
import epidemic.Epidemic;
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

    Epidemic object = new Epidemic(); 
    object.epidemic(list1, list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
}
```

I add the .jar file to java project using project->Libraries right click add external jars. Netbeans automatically detects object's methods. However I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
com/mathworks/toolbox/javabuilder/internal/MWComponentInstance
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at twittertrendsetters.TwitterTrendSetters.main(TwitterTrendSetters.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWComponentInstance
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 13 more
```

What is the issue here? Am I supposed to add something else in order the jar to work properly?

EDIT: I add the .jar file located in MATLABROOT/toolbox/javabuild/jar/javabuild.jar to my classpath and the class it seems to work. Now I am facing another problem. When I print the list1 which based on html docs takes the output of matlab .m file I got an empty arrayList. Matlab function returns an array Nx1 of doubles. How can I parse it correctly to the java arrayList.

My matlab code:

```
function eP = epidemic() // zero input

graph = dlmread('graph.edges'); //a graph
graph_ids=importdata('cms_V3_id.txt');  // indexes of the graph

for index = 1:length(graph)
 grph(index,1) = find(graph_ids == graph(index,1));
 grph(index,2) = find(graph_ids == graph(index,2));
end
grph(:,3)= graph(:,3);

grph(end + 1, :, :) = [max(max(grph)) max(max(grph)) 1 ];
grph =  spconvert(grph);

[S, prev] = brutte_topk2(grph, 3707); //function approximate pagerank result
eP = graph_ids(S); // returning a list of indexes
```

I tried to use your approach. I create a table of OBject and parse the result into it.

```
    Epidemic object = new Epidemic(); 
    Object[] result;
    result = object.epidemic(1);
    System.out.println((Double)result[0]);
```

However I am getting javabuilder.MWNumericArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Double. When I print just the reuslt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you need to add to the Java project classpath:

- the deployed JAR file you [created](http://www.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/create-a-java-class-from-matlab-code.html) from the MATLAB code.
- [Java Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/)'s own JAR files. If you have MATLAB installed on the target machine, you can find those inside `$MATLABROOT\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar`, otherwise install the appropriate [MCR](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) runtime (available for free), and locate the JAR file in a similar path.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/integrating-a-java-class-into-an-application.html) for the full instructions.

---

## EDIT:

For the sake of completeness, below is a working example.

1. Assume we have the following MATLAB function that returns a array of numbers.

   #### epidemic.m

   ```matlab
   function list = epidemic()
       list = randi(100, [1, 10]);
   end
   ```
2. Using the `applicationCompiler` MATLAB app, create a new project to build a "Java Package". Add the above function to the project, set class and method names, then build the package. We should get a JAR file, say: `Epidemic.jar`
3. Next we create a Java program to test the above package. For example:

   #### TestEpidemic.java

   ```java
   import java.util.*;
   import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;  // MATLAB Java Builder
   import Epidemic.*;                           // our compiled package

   public class TestEpidemic {
       public double[] getArray() throws MWException {
           Epidemic obj = null;
           Object[] out = null;
           double [] arr = null;
           try {
               obj = new Epidemic();
               out = obj.epidemic(1);  // request one output
               arr = (double[]) ((MWArray)out[0]).getData();
           } catch (MWException e) {
               System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
           } finally {
               MWArray.disposeArray(out);
               obj.dispose();
           }
           return arr;
       }

       public static void main (String[] args) {
           try {
               TestEpidemic e = new TestEpidemic();
               double[] arr = e.getArray();
               for(double x : arr) {
                   System.out.println(x);
               }
           } catch (Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally we compile and run the test program:

   ```
   javac.exe -classpath "%MATLABROOT%\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar";.\Epidemic.jar TestEpidemic.java

   java.exe -classpath .;"%MATLABROOT%\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar";.\Epidemic.jar TestEpidemic
   ```

   you should see an array of 10 double numbers printed.

Comment: In matlabroot I have got bot javabuilder/jar folder and javabuilder/jar/win64. Which of the two folder I have got to add to path? Moreover I have got to add it to enviroment path or classpath? Which is the difference?

Comment: @FereRes: No you must add the *JAR files* to your NetBeans project (add them to the Java [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)), just like you did the other ones. You should pick the version that matches the architecture of the machine, JVM and MATLAB (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: Yea I think that this solved the problem. However now I am getting another problem: Exception in thread "main" ... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
file C:\Users\chrathan\AppData\Local\Temp\chrathan\mcrCache8.3\epidem0\epidemic\epidemic.m, name epidemic, line 20.
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException

Comment: @FereRes: that's a runtime exception thrown by the MATLAB code. Could be that you gave the function the wrong kind of input? Check your original code in the `epide‌​mic.m` file at line 20...

Comment: In .m file in the following which is actually  return on list of integers eP function eP = epidemic(). In java code I create an object Epidemic object = new Epidemic(). The next step to use the function epidemic. In the html docs it shows me that there are three ways to use that method. Either using as method arguments two lists, or two Object obj or one integer and one Object. In Matlab code I haven't any argument. So when I am using two lists as argument it shows me the previous error.

Comment: @Armo, the problem was in Matlab code, I compmile again the .m file  now it works fine. However As a result I am getting an empty arraylist. I have updated the code.

Comment: @FereRes: it would also help to see the MATLAB code.. What are the expected inputs and outputs? Usually compiled functions are called as `result = obj.method(nout, a, b, c, ...)` where `nout` is the number of requested outputs, and the rest of arguments `a,b,c,...` are the inputs. `result` should be defined as an object array `Object[]`, then cast each `result[i]` to a more specific `MWArray` class depending on the type of outputs (there is support for automatic conversions). This is all explained in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/about-the-matlab-builder-ja-api.html).

Comment: @FereRes: `MWNumericArray` class has a `getDoubleData()` method to retrieve the `double[]` values.

Comment: @FereRes: I added a full example

Answer (score 7):

A JAR file can only return an exit code if it contains a main method. The type of the return value is an integer. You can achieve this if you use `System.exit(returnCode)`.

If you mean that you have another project in which you want to embedd this project, you have to get rid of the right dependencies and just call the method from the JAR you want.

Comment: I ve got a java project and I want to embed there a jar file(from matlab code). Is it possible to create a function in matlab code which will return a vector of integers, and call it to java code from jar?

Comment: @FereRes So you've got a JAR file from matlab. Containing what? Code? Other files? Main method? If it is a normal JAR file with classes you can go to your project and edit the included libraries.

Comment: In Matlab code I got a function which I compile it as a jar using a class name for example class1. How can I see the structure of the jar file? I mean I don't know what it's inside.

Comment: @FereRes Just extract it with 7Zip for example.