# how to run jar files that created by matlab in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, jar

I try to run the code that published here ([Return value from jar file created from Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374534/return-value-from-jar-file-created-from-matlab?answertab=active#tab-top)) building a jar file in matlab and run it in eclipse.
i did exactly as "amro" source code in the link but i have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Epidemic.TestEpidemic.getArray(TestEpidemic.java:29)
at Epidemic.TestEpidemic.main(TestEpidemic.java:37)
```

I noticed the error is when i try to do:

```
obj = new Epidemic();
```

By the way, i build the jar file in matlab using "deploytool" command.